# Why until successful of Mule gets the response from the third party however never passes to the calling party

Tags: mule

As you can see that I have used until successful at flow level and connector
level however the response does't comes back to the calling party however
the retries is successfully executed

```xml
<until-successful objectStore-ref="objectStore" maxRetries="2"             
        secondsBetweenRetries="60" doc:name="Until Successful">
    <flow-ref name="xml-to-servlet" doc:name="xml-to-servlet"/>
</until-successful>
<sub-flow name="xml-to-servlet" doc:name="xml-to-servlet">
    <custom-transformer class="MapToTemplate" doc:name="MapToTemplate">              
        <spring:property name="sessionBean" ref="SessionBean"/>
    </custom-transformer>
    <custom-transformer class="LogTime" doc:name="Logging">                 
        <spring:property name="state" value="SEND_TIME"/>
    </custom-transformer>
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" method="POST"    
            address="http://localhost:8080/Xml_Servlet_Simulator/XmlServlet"  
            doc:name="HTTP" responseTimeout="60000" keep-alive="true">
        <set-property propertyName="eig_requestId" value="#[sessionVars.REQUEST_ID]"/>                              
    </http:outbound-endpoint> 
    <custom-transformer class="LogTime" doc:name="Logging">
        <spring:property name="state" value="RECIEVE_TIME"/>
    </custom-transformer>
    <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
```

Comment: I looks like your xml code is not complete. I see a subflow called "xml-to-servlet" that doesn't close at the end, and a "global" until-successful tag not inside a flow... Can you also explain the problem, you're having better, please?

Comment: In Until successfull, Remove ObjectStore ( If not async you needed), Under Threading tab ,enable 'synchronous' to get the response for calling party.

Comment: Thank u guys for your attention however I am using mule 3.4 so I do not have the option for sync option in until successful

Comment: If there is any other option to synchronize the flow please let me know as I have also tried with processingStratagey="synchrnous" in the main flow  <flow name="Xml-Servlet" doc:name="Xml-Servlet" processingStrategy="synchronous">

Answer (score 0):

until-successful is asynchronous by default. So the rest of the calling flow will execute without waiting for the result of the until-successful regardless whether it was successful or not.

You can however configure it o be synchronous as documented here: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Until+Successful+Scope#UntilSuccessfulScope-SynchronousUntil-Successful

Comment: Thanks Ryan I appreciate your response as  I said I am using mule 3.4 so is there any other way to synchronize the flow

Comment: Exception thrown inside until-successful org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerMessagingException: org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod cannot be cast to java.lang.String (java.lang.ClassCastException). Message payload is of type: PostMethod
DEBUG 2015-05-19 11:04:45,219 [[eig].HTTP_HTTPS.receiver.20] org.mule.routing.SynchronousUntilSuccessfulProcessingStrategy: org.mule.api.MuleRuntimeException: org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerMessagingException: org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod cannot be cast to java.lang.String (java.lang.ClassCastException).

Comment: Using mule 3.5 I am getting the above error after checking the synchronous checkbox . I have the third party as a simulator and I am starting the server of the third party after sending a request from mule

Comment: However the request and response works properly if the third party is up and running when a request is made from the mule but when I am putting the third party in debug mode or trying to delay the third party the above exception is thrown please suggest

Comment: Hi Ryan thanks a lot I have achieved retry using until successful at connector level in mule 3.5 ie at HTTP inbound endpoint however still looking for the same at flow level and for mule 3.4